# I'm trying to export a Python list to a .txt file, but the text file ends up having too few lines

Tags: python, export

I have a list (List) of 4196 elements, all equal to either -1 or 1. I want to export the list to a .txt file. Here's the code I used:

```
file = open('file.txt','w')
for item in List:
     print>>file, item
```

For some reason, the .txt file only has 2870 elements.  (The same thing happened when I tried another way of exporting the list, but I know there are 4196 elements!)

Thanks for any help,

Zach

Comment: Also, what is `List` in this context? The code in your question is invalid

Comment: The line `print>>file.txt, item` is not proper syntax. Did you mean `print >> file, item`? (@moopet: he mentions in the text that List is the list of 4196 elements)

Comment: @DavidRobinson it probably is, but since we don't see it being created and the rest of the code is dodgy, it could be mangled

Comment: @moopet: No, he says "I have a list (List) of 4196 elements." It's not reproducible, but it's also not ambiguous what List is.

Comment: Thank you, I meant file, not file.txt

Comment: You're right, I read it poorly

Comment: @user1590405: Did you try putting the line `print len(list)` right before the for loop, just to make *absolutely* sure of the length of the list?

Comment: You could try `file.write('\n'.join(str(x) for x in List)); file.close()`, but that really shouldn't make a difference.  (did you remember `file.close()?`)

Comment: I did make absolutely sure of the length of the list before exporting.  I also tried this with an artificial List = [1]*4196.  The resulting text file had 4096 lines (up from 2870, but still missing 100 lines).  Perhaps there's some character limit I'm running up against?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to close the file. You can’t easily tell from the number of lines, but I’d expect the size of the file to be 4096 or 8192, which hints that only a whole number of blocks have been flushed. After you call `file.close()`, the rest of the data should be written.

You can use a `with` statement to [close the file automatically](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file.close):

```
with open('file.txt','w') as file:
    for item in List:
        print>>file, item
```

Comment: I think you're right here (see my comment above).  Buffering is most likely the cause of these problems (and they can be avoided using a context manager as proposed by @dm03514)

Comment: +1, Context managers are always the best way to deal with files. It might be worth noting that using ``print`` in this way is a little odd - and the functionality is different in 3.x - for these reasons, you might want to use ``file.write()`` instead, which is clearer.

Comment: @Lattyware -- using print like this isn't weird at all.  It's the same thing as python 3's `print(this,that,file=file)` as far as I'm aware.  The behavior is slightly different than `f.write` as well.  (`print` automgically calls `str` on it's arguments and appends a newline unless you tell it not to).  That said, I always hated that syntax and would prefer `f.write( ... )` as you suggest.

Comment: @mgilson Weird might be the wrong choice of word - I don't think it's very expressive. As soon as you see ``file.write(...)`` you expect writing to a file, ``print`` - not so much. I just don't really see the benefit to it here over ``file.write(str(item)+"\n")`` - I prefer the explicit option over the slightly less verbose, but that could just be me.

Comment: @Lattyware -- No, it's not just you.  Like I said, I prefer `f.write(...)` as well (and quite strongly -- I hate that old syntax). My comment was mainly to document the differences between the two methods.  (Imagine Op's surprise when trying to convert directly to `f.write(item)` and it complains because `item` isn't a string.  And then there are no newlines in the file after going to `f.write(str(item))` ...

Comment: @mgilson You make a good point, the differences are important.

Answer (score -1):

Something like this?

```
List = open("file.txt").read()
new = []
ff = open("new_file.txt", 'w')
for i in List:
    new.append(i)
ff.write(str(new))
ff.close()
```

Comment: ``CapWords`` names are usually reserved for classes according to [PEP-8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). It's also worth noting this is a very inefficient way to produce such a list (a list comp, or, better yet, ``file.readlines()`` would be a much better option in a case like this, and will produce a file containing a Python list literal, which isn't what was wanted.

Comment: This will require reading the file into memory, which could cause problems with big files or low memory systems.